# Save a rest request in spring boot before validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

is there a way to save a rest web service request in a spring boot application before validating the request??

I have to return the save the request, validate the request and in case of errors, send the error back. In case of a successful validation, the request should be processed..

Comment: What do you mean “save the request?” Save where? Why? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Save the request in a database. I have not tried anything yet. The request needs to be saved for audit

Comment: Save it then, what’s the problem? You don’t know how to make database calls?

Comment: I want to save it before the validation.. not after it..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the request before save then use bean validation on your request body external json object...or if you don't wanted to validate the request object then it's automatically save into database.

Comment: The system currently does bean validation.. I want to get a copy of the request before validation is done and save the request..

Comment: Check it out how to handle incoming request. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging